# Check string index exist

Tags: linux, bash

how to we check if string index is exist in array for example

```
declare -A SArray
SArray[a]="a"
SArray[b]="b"

read index
```

now on index i want to check if index is exist in SArray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A SArray
SArray[a]="a"
SArray[b]="b"
read index

if test "${SArray["$index"]+isset}"; then
    echo "index $index exists for SArray"
else
    echo "no index $index for SArray"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

In `bash` 4.3, you can use the `-v` operator.

```
if [[ -v SArray[a] ]]; then
    echo "${SArray[a]}"
else
    echo "a is not a key in Sarray"
fi
```